# counting positive items in an array without using any conditional jump

Tags: arrays, y86

How can I do this ?

I think I should do something like calculating checksum but this should give number of positive integers in final bits.

edit: what if we can't use 'shift', either

edit2: ISA is [Y86](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~hollingd/comporg/notes/Y86/Y86.pdf)

Comment: Now that you've revealed that this is a made-up ISA, this question feels somewhat contrived.  I think the answer is that you will have to rely on conditionals to solve this problem.

Comment: No. This question is not contrived. I code in y86 assembly language and want to see how much more can I optimize it. I cleaned almost all data hazards. However, this control hazard is tough to get rid of. The reason why I said that programming language does not matter is the fact that any technique that eliminates this branches can be implemented in most of the programming languages. If we talk about 'C' there is no way to fail to do this kind of optimization that you can do in assembly.

Comment: note: I'm using y86 simulator YIS.

Answer (score 2):

Since I see you are very concerned about performance: If you can code in assembly language, then for each element of the array you can subtract the element from zero (or do some similar trick that will set the carry flag if the element was positive) and then execute the "ADC" instruction (or similar) with a zero operand. ADC is an instruction that almost all CPUs offer, and it stands for "Add with Carry". It will add the operand, plus the value of the carry flag of the CPU, to the accumulator. So, if the element was positive, then the subtraction from zero would have set the carry flag, which means that the accumulator will be incremented; otherwise, the carry flag would be cleared, so the accumulator will not be incremented. I do not think it can get any faster than that.

Comment: IMO, counter-voting is even worse than anonymous downvoting.  Your vote should represent your assessment of the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with integer types, then it is guaranteed that the msb of a non-negative number is 0.<sup>*</sup>  So all you need to do is isolate the msb of each array element in turn, and accumulate.

---

<sub>* This is true for two's-complement, one's-complement and sign-magnitude.</sub>

Comment: so you suppose I may use arithmetic shifts for isolating msb?

Comment: @bfaskiplar: You can use logical or arithmetic shifts, and then bit-masking.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if our ISA does not support shift? (It does only add, sub, xor and and)

Comment: yes, it is clear that it is going to be tricky. I need to know what the trick is.

Comment: @bfaskiplar: By tricky, I mean "probably impossible to do fast", unless you can tell us more about your instruction set.

Comment: it is y86. for Y86 there is a reference here -> http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ch4-preview.pdf

Comment: @bfaskiplar: Ok, I will take a look.  But as you are looking for an ISA-specific solution, you should edit your original question to make this clear...

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more efficient to use conditions, but you could loop through the array, adding the sign bits together.

You haven't specified a language, so I'll use pseudocode, assuming 32-bit signed integers:

```
Set accumulator to 0
For each element in array
    sign = (element bitwise and 0x80000000) logical shift right by 31
    accumulator += sign
positive_count = length of array - accumulator
```

Comment: it wouldn't be more efficient. Have you heard about control hazards or how mispredicted jumps decreases program performance ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_hazards

Comment: Maybe - depends on what processor you were running this on. On a 68HC11 and, branch and increment will run in the same number of cycles as and, shift and add, depending on the memory access mode

Comment: Actually, branch will run faster on the 68HC11 as shift will only work a single bit place at a time

Comment: one misprediction costs 2 additional cycles in Y86, When taking this into account , It is wise to use and shift rather than and,branch,increment